# PlantUML: Disable visibility icons on relations

Tags: plantuml

I know that I can turn of the visibility icons with `skinparam classAttributeIconSize 0` to get the regular symbols `-`, `#`, `~` and `+` instead of the icons. While this works well for class attributes, the visibility is simply not rendered at all for labels on relations:

```
@startuml
skinparam classAttributeIconSize 0
Bob -- Alice: "-private"
@enduml
```

renders

[image: actual output]

How do I achieve the following?

[image: expected output]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is intended (removing the minus sign at the first position) or a bug, but the following worked, as a workaround:

```
@startuml
skinparam classAttributeIconSize 0
Bob -- Alice: " -private"
@enduml
```

Note the space before the minus sign.

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed a nice workaround. With the leading space the `-` is simply not interpreted at all. You get the same result even without setting `classAttributeIconSize` to 0.